# Facing issues while hiding div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am creating a table and hide it immediately after its creation. [don't want to face DOM]. then  user select from dropdown and i show it. its working fine. but when i go to that page for the first time it does not hide that div.

**code**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered " id="book_info" >
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    ...
    </td>  
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <script> $('#book_info').hide();
            alert("passed");
  </script>
    <!-- remaining html stuff-->
```

that alert do not hit when i goto that page. when i refresh the page ,it shows alert...

Comment: Why not just use CSS? `#book_info {display:none;}`?

Comment: then how to display it back?

Comment: You would need a trigger for that, a click function for example or another event (like hover). You might need to post more of your HTML.

Comment: jQuerys .show() will work for you. You are probably using that already as you say the show-part works?

Comment: You would continue to show it the way you do now.

Comment: it don't show alert("passed")..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your jQuery method calls in a [document `ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#book_info').hide();
    ...
});
```

Alternatively you could just use CSS to initially render the table hidden:

```css
#book_info {
    display: none;
}
```

...then call jQuery's `show()` method when you want to display it:

```
$('#book_info').show();
```

Comment: it seems you are using bootstrap just use class "hide" with table and by default table would be hidden ,then use your jquery code to display it back